# Can't connect remotely without bind-address, can't connect locally with it

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with mysql.  I am trying to allow remote access.  I found that if I write in my.cnf:

bind-address=my.ip.address

It works remotely, but using a php script that tries to access the database using the same ip doesn't work anymore!

If I remove this line, I can connect locally, but not remotely.

I tried setting it to 0.0.0.0, which has the same effect as if it were not there at all.

I saw that you can't bind to multiple addresses unfortunately.  Any way to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MYSQL User accounts have 2 parts

1. The userid
2. The domain from which they can connect to this MYSQL Server instance

EG `'root'@'localhost'`

So you need to create a new user account, you dont want to give access to the `root` id externally, and make this new userid allowed to connect from either a specific ip address (*more secure*) or any ip address

From the command line `mysql.exe` processor you woudl do this

```
CREATE USER 'somone'@'11.22.33.44' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

for a specific ip address

Or

```
CREATE USER 'somone'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

To allow access from any ip adddress in the universe, so better make the password a good strong one

Then you allocate privilages to one or more databases to this new account

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP
ON database_name.*
TO 'someone'@'%';
```

> References
>
> CREATE USER http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html
>
> Grant http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I think that did it.  I have been messing with a gui program for these permissions and managed to mess things up. But after looking at this answer I was able to get things cleared up.  Thanks.